# Branding Acrobat text box as part of PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Acrobat Version: 8.1.0

After adding a textbox to PDF,
Is there a way so that, textbox can be part of PDF document?

I don't want people to be able to change/move textbox context and I would like to "brand" it as part of PDF.
And I cannot password protected PDF document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally print/publish to PDF from Acrobat to make everything work nicely together.  You still retain the ability to search/select text, and all the objects are neatly merged.

There may be another more elegant solution though...

Comment: @sound2man: "Printing" to PDF again did the trick for me.